# Why don't Linear regression accepts Series of data as first argument?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[image]

As you can infer from above, when I pass series of data as argument to Linear regression model , it throws an error.

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2600 3000 3200 3600 4000].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Because the predictors for linear regression should be a matrix, even if you only have one variable, you should format it as a matrix to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function requires you to input an array of shape (n1,n2), if you check the [vignette](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit):

> X: {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
> Training data
>
> y: array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_targets) Target
> values. Will be cast to X’s dtype if necessary

Even when you have a pandas Series, the shape of this object is (n,):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
y = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

X.shape                                                                                                   
#(100,)
```

You can convert them to a dataframe or convert to numpy array with the correct shape:

```
reg = LinearRegression().fit(pd.DataFrame(X), y)
```

or:

```
reg = LinearRegression().fit(np.array(X).reshape(-1,1),y)
```